# How do I disable the spam filter in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I'd like to disable the spam filter in Gmail, how can I do this?

Comment: why would you want to do that o_0

Comment: @Sathya: see this related question I asked: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/when-using-gmail-with-multiple-accounts-should-each-account-have-a-spam-filter

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Create a **new filter** in Gmail.
2. Enter `is:spam` in the **Has the words:** field.
3. A warning will appear warning you not to use the word `is:` in the filter, you can safely ignore it by pressing **OK**.
4. Check the **Never send it to Spam** checkbox.
5. Click **Create Filter**.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the method may have been banned by Google, I use this:

2. Enter something crazy in **Does not have words:** like faewfaefagvfdvfaefeffdvcvfea
3. Check the **Never send it to Spam** checkbox.

Otherwise the same as above. If Google will ban this too, I will update this.