# Does Gmail forward Spam after you've setup forwarding?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, email-forwarding

Sometimes Gmail sees a genuine message as Spam by accident and then automatically marks the message, moving it to the Spam folder.
So in my case I've setup my Gmail account to forward the incoming mail to my alternative email address.
My question now is, does Gmail forward Spam messages as well? I need to understand how this works in order to setup either a filter to recognize important emails based on addresses or to go and un-mark the genuine emails in Spam every now and then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not. If you want the emails flagged as spam to be forwarded, create a filter on some gibberish like `-sdflkmdfl87987` (meaning all emails that don't contain "sdflkmdfl87987") that includes all emails you're likely to receive and check "Never send it to Spam".

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to forward all Gmail messages to another account *including* spam?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9322)