# How can I remove spam filtering in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the spam filter in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/how-do-i-disable-the-spam-filter-in-gmail)

Is there any way disable the spam folder and let all my messages come to my inbox?

Answer (score 9):

This may seem awkward, but you have to:

- Click the arrow on the search box
- Enter `is:spam` in the "Has the words" field
- Click "Create filter with this search »"

  [image]
- Accept the warning message

  [image]
- Change the filter so the spam is never sent to spam (sic!)

  [image]