# Gmail: emails won't stay in inbox when moved back from bin

Tags: gmail

For some strange reason some of my emails go straight to the bin, when I move the email back into the inbox and refresh it automatically gets moved back into the bin and I have no idea why this is happening and how I can prevent it. I have deleted all my filters and disabled POP incase that was causing it.

This happens when I access gmail on my laptop and when I use my phone.

My case sounds similar to this one, but I'm not accessing my emails with a email client other than my phone: [When I move spam to my inbox, it goes back into the spam again](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54811/when-i-move-spam-to-my-inbox-it-goes-back-into-the-spam-again)

Comment: Are you using the Gmail app on your phone?

Comment: Are you using any other third-party apps to help manage your mail? You can see the apps that have access to your account in the "Connected apps & sites" section at https://myaccount.google.com/security

Comment: Yes I am using Gmail on my phone and Type mail, another android email app, I found the solution to fix my problem which I'll share below.

Comment: Are your messages going to "Bin" (the British English equivalent to "Trash") or are they going to "Spam". There's a significant difference there, and your question seems to be using the two terms interchangeably.

Comment: Yes they were definitely going to the Bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix to my problems, I'll list the steps I took below but I have no idea why it worked

- Delete all my filters
- Select all the emails in my bin that refused to be moved directly back to the inbox
- Mark all the emails as Spam
- Go to the Spam folder, select all the emails again and mark as Not Spam
- voila they move into my inbox and not the bin
- All new emails that were previously being binned are now going into my inbox and staying there

Like I said no idea why marking and un-marking it as Spam fixed the problem but it did.