# How to disable Gmail's spam filter?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the spam filter in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/how-do-i-disable-the-spam-filter-in-gmail)

How to disable Gmail's spam filter?  I'd prefer to manually filter them as my account has low enough traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a bogus filter as detailed [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-deactivate-spam-filter-protection-in-gmail-or-google-mail/) should do the trick. Not copy-pasting the entire tutorial since I don't know if it (still) works.